# How do I merge the tabs of two safari windows when I have more than two open?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

So far, I know how I can merge *all* windows with all their tabs using:

[image]

I use different windows in safari to organize them by content. Sometimes it makes sense to merge the tabs of two windows. This very easy when you have only two Safari windows open.

How can I do this when I have more than two windows? I'm open to solutions using extensions.

Comment: You can drag tabs between windows, what happens if you drag the whole window onto another?

Comment: @StuWilson: That doesn't do anything.
gentmatt: There's always individually dragging each tab over, but as far as I know of, there are no native or third-party ways to merge entire windows selectively.

Comment: @StuWilson I really did not know that dragging of individual tabs works! How come I did not try this? :) Make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can drag tabs between windows in safari (I beleive this was added in Safari 4 along with a few other improvements)

Comment: You have to have two or more tabs in the second window, first.

Comment: I opened a new Window and used the `View -> Show Tab Bar` menu option, and now I always have a tab bar even with one tab, which makes things easier w/r/t the previous comment from @JossieCalderon.

Answer (score 16):

First, if the tab bar isn't showing (it usually doesn't show unless there are multiple tabs in the window), select the 1st window you want to merge, then at the menu bar at the top of the screen click View->Show Tab Bar. Next drag the now visible tab bar to the window you want to merge with.

Comment: This is the correct procedure if one of the windows has no tabs.

Comment: Alternatively you could (possibly just as easily) make a new tab and drag the original one over. You would need to close the new tab you made, however.

Comment: This seems to persist across Safari window launches too, so once you've done it once, it seems to always keep the tab bar open even for single windows.

Answer (score 4):

If you have many tabs open in a window, it might become hard to drag each of them over. In this case you could bookmark all pages in the current window (**Bookmarks > Add Bookmark for These Tabs...**), go to the window you want to put these tabs into, and then select **Bookmarks > (Folder you put tabs as bookmarks into) > Open in New Tabs**.

Do note however that this will cause all of your tabs in the window you bookmarked to be closed. You should only use this method if you are okay with that.